# Customized Linux system, wired and wireless connectivity interoperability?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

The Linux system I customized runs on device A, which uses an ARM processor. Device A has an `eth2` (fixed IP 192.168.5.1) and a `wlan2`, which is a wireless transmitter with a fixed IP 192.168.1.6. My computer can connect to device A through 192.168.1.6, but in this case, without wired connection, I can still log in to device A using 192.168.5.1; But if I am unable to log in to device A using 192.168.1.6 after connecting it with a wired connection, what is the problem?

```
[root@dobot ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan2
192.168.5.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
[root@dobot ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4E:BF:B7:B3:54:5F
          inet6 addr: fe80::4cbf:b7ff:feb3:545f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8681 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2
          TX packets:8689 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:627545 (612.8 KiB)  TX bytes:356046 (347.7 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:C6:87:72:01
          inet addr:192.168.100.6  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:C6:87:72:01
          inet addr:192.168.5.1  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20e:c6ff:fe87:7201/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2545558 (2.4 MiB)  TX bytes:5457600 (5.2 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:60760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3955747 (3.7 MiB)  TX bytes:3955747 (3.7 MiB)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D0:37:45:8A:68:90
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d237:45ff:fe8a:6890/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:157031 errors:0 dropped:589 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15430 errors:0 dropped:82 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2875938 (2.7 MiB)  TX bytes:4311430 (4.1 MiB)
```

I understand it this way, `eth2` and `wlan2` have different identities. `eth2` is a terminal, while `wlan2` is a node (with the function of assigning IP). The reason why 192.168.1.6 and 192.168.1. x cannot connect to 192.168.1.100 ping when wired is because 192.168.1.1 does not have routing forwarding function; When connected wirelessly, 192.168.1.x can ping 192.168.1.x because of the special nature of `wlan2`, so 192.168.1.x can also ping 192.168.1.x.

Comment: I am confused by ```I can still log in to device A using 192.168.1.1```.  Also, what does ```traceroute``` show when you try to connect to A with & without the ethernet connection.

Comment: @Garnet The results of `traceroute` are same.

Comment: Your updated answer confused me even more.  What device is 192.168.1.1?  Are you trying to connect from device A or to device A?  It would be helpful if you updated your answer with the output of ```traceroute``` with & without the ethernet cable plugged in because if the traceroutes are really ```the same```, you should be able to ping 192.168.1.100 with or without the ethernet cable plugged in.