# linux Invalid ip_forward setting

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

The Linux system I customized runs on device A, which uses an ARM processor. Device A has two network cards: `eth2` (fixed IP: 192.168.5.1) and `wlan2` (fixed IP: 192.168.1.6). `wlan2` is a USB to WiFi transmitter. When I disable data forwarding by executing `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, but `ping 192.168.1.6` was still successful. What's going on?

```
[root@dobot ~]# echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
[root@dobot ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
[root@dobot ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.5.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan2
192.168.5.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
[root@dobot ~]# ifconfig eth2
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:C6:87:72:01
          inet addr:192.168.5.1  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20e:c6ff:fe87:7201/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37729 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55791 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3182517 (3.0 MiB)  TX bytes:7180021 (6.8 MiB)

[root@dobot ~]# ifconfig wlan2
wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D0:37:45:8A:68:90
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d237:45ff:fe8a:6890/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1110732 errors:0 dropped:503 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:32466 (31.7 KiB)  TX bytes:364864 (356.3 KiB)
```

Comment: Why do you believe that pinging the address of one of the network interfaces on the host has anything to do with forwarding? What am I missing? Also, your text says that `eth2` has the address 192.168.1.1, but your `ifconfig eth2` output says that it is 192.168.5.1. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' `Why do you believe that pinging the address of one of the network interfaces on the host has anything to do with forwarding?` I found it elsewhere and thought it was like this, but I'm not sure, so I asked the question.

Comment: This is the 4th question on the same topic. The 3 others: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769770/customized-linux-system-wired-and-wireless-connectivity-interoperability , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769780/why-does-the-use-of-traceroute-not-display-the-ip-address-of-the-route , https://superuser.com/questions/1831152/why-does-tracert-not-display-the-ip-passing-through-the-router (where you accepted the answer but also complained it didn't help for the others) . Looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @A.B I am deeply sorry for the `XY problem`, mainly because I do not have a deep understanding of it, so I believe they are not `XY problem`.

Comment: Let me guess: your questions revolve around the difference between *routing* and *bridging*, possibly to try and reproduce the behavior of an Access Point. But you're not telling what you intend to do, you're only asking why some measurement (traceroute) doesn't behave as you think it should behave. Your setup doesn't make much sense because each time two NICs are using the same IP LAN without being bridged and without the hint of Proxy ARP. You fail to give proper values (the CIDR: /24) when stating addresses etc.

Comment: @A.B First of all, thank you very much for your reply. My ultimate goal is to prevent external PCs from pinging the IP address of eth2 on device A when connecting to device A's wlan2.